# Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

I’m trying to build my Flutter project in Xcode, but I keep getting the following error:

Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

I’ve tried reinstalling Xcode several times through the App Store and normal download but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to upgrade your Flutter to the newest version.
After upgrading the XCode to 14.3 I had the same problem, and upgrading Flutter to newest version (3.7.11 in my case) helped.

**Solution**:

```
flutter upgrade
```

**Source**: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124433

It says that this problem has been fixed in Flutter 3.7.10.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the minimum iOS deployment target to 11.0, from your `Podfile`:

```
 platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Maybe there's a pod you're using but the deployment target is not suitable.

**Why setting 11.0?** Because it is supported by majority of the pods and iOS devices. This worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunaly it still does not work. The app worked fine until yesterday when there appeared an update of XCode. I propose that this update caused the issue.

Comment: Are you able to run the basic flutter counter app on the simulator @Luca_54?

Comment: Got it, I guess there's a specific package in your pubspec.yaml that adds a pod to iOS side and it's not aligning well with the deployment target. Check once with the documentation of that package on its pub.dev Readme page. @Luca_54

Comment: till 2 days before it worked. suddenly I too get this error. same code, no change. any solution? error "but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
     /var/folders/ll/h6sb3gwx1sz95139gvn2781r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Sb8MfD/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8YrlYA/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a"

Comment: platform :ios, '11.0', didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @anand Correct this issue is of recent nature, it's being tracked here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727527

Comment: I resolved it by meticulously inspecting each of my flutter packages to ensure that it was functioning properly. This seems to be a new issue with the previous flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. By going to Runner (Project) -> Configurations -> Profile -> and setting the value to profile it should work.

https://www.wafrat.com/fixing-ld-file-not-found-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoolchain-usr-lib-arc-libarclite_iphoneos-a/